# How can I get a Shockwave Flash Object enabled in active designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, shockwave

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I just cannot add a Shockwave Flash Object to my project.
I try to add the Toolbox item via COM Components and it gives me the following error

"The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer:"

Below that it states

"Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework version."

I have attempted to add the reference for Shockwave Flash Object it puts Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll in the Bin folder but still gives me the same error message when I try to add Shockwave Flash to the Toolbox.

I have also tried changing the .NET version of the project from 4.51 to 2 and 3.5 and that doesn't help either.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have this issue as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT use activex components in WPF. At least, not out of the box. You have to use something like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms742735.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396